# Call Django view function from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I want to get the list of my existing users when a page loads. Everything works when getting the information from the Angular script, but it will be stored serverside. I've made a Django view:

```
def getUsers(request):
response = {}
response['user'] = {
    'username': 'guy1',
    'password': 'guy1',
    'fName': 'John',
    'lName': 'Smith',
    'email': 'guy1@host.com',
    'role': 'Employee',
    'theme': 'default'
}
return JsonResponse(response)
```

Currently, I just pass my user there, later it will be filled with information from a postgre DB. I think I've set the url correct:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'getUsers/', views.getUsers),
]
```

And finally, I call the view from Angular when the page loads:

```
$http.get("getUsers")
    .then(function(output) {
        $scope.testUser = output;
        console.log($scope.testUser);
    });
```

When I run everything, the browser console comes up with incorrect
[output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6gt0.png)

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that is a bad request, see if the complete url includes the correct server (like http://localhost....etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do two things here. First, change your URL pattern to look like this:

```
url(r'^getUsers/$', views.getUsers),
```

Second, change your AngularJS code to look like this:

```
$http.get("getUsers/")
  .then(function(output) {
    $scope.testUser = output;
    console.log($scope.testUser);
});
```

Django is sensitive to the "/" being (or not being) on the URL. And changing the URL pattern above makes it explicit what it should be looking for. In your original case that pattern would match on `getUsers` or `getUsers/abc` or `getUsers/12345`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to have solved it, I'm now getting the data passed in the browse console.